# Unable to convert XML string containing '&' or ';' to JSON object

Tags: java, playframework

I want to convert XML String to a JSON object.

Below is the XML:

```
<request>
    <Products>
        <Product>
            <ProductName>H &amp; M</ProductName>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <totalProductCost>17.03</totalProductCost>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</request>
```

This XML string comes as a request parameter.
`httpReqMap` is the map containing request parameters and their values.
When I execute this statement

```
String reqstring = httpReqMap.get("request");
```

breaks the XML string in 2 parts. Thus the XML is invalid and I am unable to convert it to JSON Object.

I have tried to pass '&' as '&amp;'.

Below is the code:

```
String reqstring = httpReqMap.get("request");
JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(httpReqMap.get("request"));
```

It should escape special character and convert XML to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best option is to pass the XML as the payload of a POST query, not in the URL.

If you *really* want to do that, you must url-encode the whole xml. There is a number of questions on this subject, for example [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042).